# Recover PostgreSql database 9.1 with Mac

Tags: postgresql

I work with PostgreSql and PgAdmin, and I have had an accident that drives to format my Mac, here I have two options, recover all system via TimeMahine or install all from zero.

I have chosen install from zero, but I need to recover the old PostgreSql database, now I’m installing all again, pgAdmin… etc, but I don’t have any backup of my old database, I have  the old PostgreSql database system files (thanks to TimeMachine),

How can I recover the old database to the new one?

I tried to do this, from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup-file.html

```
tar -cf backup.tar /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

the problem is that the data files are (I think) in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data` and the folder is encrypted or hidden ¿?

[image]

and I can't execute `tar` command this is what happens:

```
 tar -cf backup.tar "/Volumes/backup/Backups.backupdb/MacBook, MacBook Pro de Albert/2014-04-30-112220/Macintosh HD/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data"
```

I get this error:

```
tar: /Volumes/backup/Backups.backupdb/MacBook, MacBook Pro de Albert/2014-04-30-112220/Macintosh HD/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Comment: Presumably this `data` is a symbolic link to a directory that no longer exists on your disk(s), or is accessible with a different path.

Answer (score 0):

Another option was to copy the TimeMachine folder /9.1/ beside the new 9.3 and try this:

[How to restore a file system level copy of a PostgreSQL database (not dump) to a different PC](https://serverfault.com/questions/336817/how-to-restore-a-file-system-level-copy-of-a-postgresql-database-not-dump-to-a)

but when executing pg_dump asked me a pasword I didn't had.

The solution for dummies: Uninstall pgAdmin 9.3, and install pgAdmin 9.1, here detects the folder 9.1 and tell me It was going to use it ¡perfect! it is exactly what I need.

Now I can keep 9.1 or upgrade to 9.3

Comment: There is no "pgAdmin 9.1" or "pgAdmin 9.3"

Comment: Sorry: pgAdmin es the app in a Mac tat control server-database-tables,... etc very usefull , pgAdmin installation creates this folders and the databases